# HTML/jQuery on click show/hide ul ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML code

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">link</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">link</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
```

now I want -> hide all sub menus -> if I click to main li element -> show current li's sub menu and next if I click to another main li element show sub menu and hide previously displayed sub menu.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow merfiduke. Please show what you have tried so far and where did you get stuck. You cannot expect people to write code for you, you need to demonstrate some effort first (and then ask a more specific question). I also recommend reading the [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something simple like this with click event

```js
$('#main>li>a').click(function() { // bind click event to a tag
  $(this)
    .next() // get ul inside
    .stop() // stop any previous animation
    .slideToggle() // toggle the visibility
    .end() // back to previous selector , here the clicked element
    .parent() // get parent li
    .siblings() // get its siblings
    .find('ul') // get ul inside them
    .stop() // stop any previous animation
    .slideUp() // hide them
});
```

```css
#main>li>ul {
  /* hide sub ul initially */
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="main">
  <li><a href="#">link</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href="#">link</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">link</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/709/)

```js
$('li ul').hide();
$('li a').click(function() {
  $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
  $('ul li ul').not($(this).next('ul')).slideUp();
});
```